# Why is my df converted to nonetype and inoperable when I call a class method on it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset, let's say:

| emp_id | type | market_cap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 7.845000e+10 |
| 2 | b | 6.235000e+10 |
| 3 | c | NaN |

I have the following class:

```
class DataCleaner:
    def __init__(self, dataf):
        """this is the constructor that initializes the dataframe to be cleaned"""
        self.dataf=dataf

    def remove_upper_quantile(self, col, quantile_num):
      
        self.dataf=self.dataf[self.dataf[col<self.dataf[col].quantile(quantile_num)]
        return self.dataf


    def remove_nulls(self, col):
        self.dataf=self.dataf.dropna(subset=[col], inplace=True)
        return self.dataf
```

When I call remove_nulls on my df, like so:

```
clean_company=DataCleaner(df)
df=clean_company.remove_nulls('market_cap')
```

I get the following: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'.

This also happens when I don't assign df to the result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. The base must be in the dataframe.
2. To delete a column, use: df.pop('market_cap')

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `inplace = True` keyword argument within this method call:

```
def remove_nulls(self, col):
        self.dataf=self.dataf.dropna(subset=[col], inplace=True)
        return self.dataf
```

Looking at the documentation for the `df.dropna` method, you can see that when `inplace=True` the method will return `None`, rather than the dataframe.

You could, alternatively, just remove the `self.dataf=` component of that line and just have `self.dataf.dropna(subset=[col], inplace=True)` as that will drop the `na`s "inplace" and change the dataframe without you needing to overwrite it.